# CSS cannot set gallery to be visible

Tags: css

As in my gallery there is a lot of pictures I want to place it in a div which is visible on click.

The div which contains gallery shows up but the gallery is invisible. I cannot figure out how can I make it work.

My code:

```
<section class="bottom">

        <div class="gallery-slide">     
            <a id="gallery-slide-button"><h3 class="underline"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>Galeria</h3></a>
            <div id="gallery-slide-images">
                     <p><?php echo do_shortcode ( '[gallery captions="hide" bottomspace="ten" gutterwidth="10" columns="8" ids="83,84,85,86,87,88,89"]' ); ?>
            </p></div>  
         </div>
```

```
<script>
$( "#gallery-slide-button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#gallery-slide-images" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>

.gallery-slide > a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
color: #e15823;
-webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
transition-duration: 300ms; 
}

.gallery-slide a {color: #363635;}

#gallery-slide-images {
display: none; 
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css there is a class which makes it hidden.

```
.wc-gallery .gallery.gallery-masonry {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Change it or you can in css

```
.wc-gallery .gallery.gallery-masonry {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

if it not work use

```
.wc-gallery .gallery.gallery-masonry {
   visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it why gallery's CSS would make itself hidden but thank you for the help!

Comment: I thing for the masonry style the plugin make itself  visibility: hidden;.